# how to insert/edit QAbstractListModel in python and qml updates automatically?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, qabstractlistmodel

---

i am trying to insert/edit a python list that is subclassed from `QAbstractListModel` in pyqt5. this python list is read in the `model` property of `ListView` element in qml. i have no issues displaying the data in qml. problem arises when i try to append new data into the python list.

the following is what i have done so far:

main.py:

```
import sys, model2
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView

class MainWindow(QQuickView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.model = model2.PersonModel()
        self.rootContext().setContextProperty('PersonModel', self.model)
        self.rootContext().setContextProperty('MainWindow', self)
        self.setSource(QUrl('test2.qml'))

myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = MainWindow()
ui.show()
sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

model2.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

class PersonModel(QAbstractListModel):

    Name = Qt.UserRole + 1
    Age = Qt.UserRole + 2

    personChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.persons = [
            {'name': 'jon', 'age': 20},
            {'name': 'jane', 'age': 25}
        ]

    def data(self, QModelIndex, role):
        row = QModelIndex.row()
        if role == self.Name:
            return self.persons[row]["name"]
        if role == self.Age:
            return self.persons[row]["age"]

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.persons)

    def roleNames(self):
        return {
            Qt.UserRole + 1: b'name',
            Qt.UserRole + 2: b'age'
        }

    @pyqtSlot()
    def addData(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.persons = self.persons.append({'name': 'peter', 'age': 22})
        self.endResetModel()
        print(self.persons)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def editData(self):
        print(self.model.persons)
```

test2.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "lightgrey"

    ListView {
        id: listExample
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: PersonModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: name + " " + age
        }
    }

    Button {
        width: 50
        height: 25
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        text: "add"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("qml adding")
            PersonModel.addData()
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

error occurs when i click the add button which calls the `addData` method in model2.py. error lies in the `rowCount` and error message says `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`. do i have to emit the changes or pass in some index and role value so qml knows what is new/old and only reflect the changes accordingly?

any form of guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you get is caused by the following line of code:

```
self.persons = self.persons.append({'name': 'peter', 'age': 22})
```

It is caused because the append function does not return anything, so it was meant to assign None to self.persons

To insert new data you must call `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` to notify the view of the change.

the data method must be identical to that shown in the documentation, ie it must have the following format:

```
def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
```

The same with the rowCount method:

```
def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
```

I have implemented the methods addPerson, editPerson and deletePerson that adds, edits and deletes a data from the list respectively. Also I added the necessary items to the .qml to be able to test it.

**model2.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QModelIndex    

class PersonModel(QAbstractListModel):

    NameRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    AgeRole = Qt.UserRole + 2

    personChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.persons = [
            {'name': 'jon', 'age': 20},
            {'name': 'jane', 'age': 25}
        ]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        if role == PersonModel.NameRole:
            return self.persons[row]["name"]
        if role == PersonModel.AgeRole:
            return self.persons[row]["age"]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.persons)

    def roleNames(self):
        return {
            PersonModel.NameRole: b'name',
            PersonModel.AgeRole: b'age'
        }

    @pyqtSlot(str, int)
    def addPerson(self, name, age):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self.persons.append({'name': name, 'age': age})
        self.endInsertRows()

    @pyqtSlot(int, str, int)
    def editPerson(self, row, name, age):
        ix = self.index(row, 0)
        self.persons[row] = {'name': name, 'age': age}
        self.dataChanged.emit(ix, ix, self.roleNames())

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def deletePerson(self, row):
        self.beginRemoveColumns(QModelIndex(), row, row)
        del self.persons[row]
        self.endRemoveRows()
```

**test2.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "lightgrey"

    ListView {
        id: listExample
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: PersonModel
        delegate:
            Item {
            width: 200
            height: 60
            Row {
                Text {
                    width: 60
                    text:  name + " " + age
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                Button{
                    width: 20
                    text: "+"
                    onClicked: PersonModel.editPerson(index, name, age+1)
                }
                Button{
                    width: 20
                    text: "-"
                    onClicked: PersonModel.editPerson(index, name, age-1)
                }
                Button{
                    width: 20
                    text: "X"
                    onClicked: PersonModel.deletePerson(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        width: 50
        height: 25
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        text: "add"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("qml adding")
            PersonModel.addPerson("luis", 22)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

**.py**

```
@pyqtSlot(int, str, int)
def insertPerson(self, row, name, age):
    self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row)
    self.persons.insert(row, {'name': name, 'age': age})
    self.endInsertRows()
```

**.qml**

```
 PersonModel.insertPerson(2, "luis", 1111)
```

Comment: hey eyllanesc! thanks for replying to my question on pyqt5 and qml again! i was trying to play around with the second and third params of `beginInsertRows` method but i cant seem to insert the newly added data in between jon and jane. how should that be done? oh by the way, do you happen to know of any resources on pyqt5 and qml?

Comment: @eugeneoei Okay, in a few moments I'll create an insert method. On the second point there is no official documentation, in fact the official documentation of PyQt points to the documentation of Qt so if you know the least of C ++ you can understand it. Please do not forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: cool! i know where i had gone wrong now. was trying to append the dictionary to a specific position in the list. that will definitely not work. still very new to python. at least i know now. thanks eyllanesc!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a mistake:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(ix, ix, self.roleNames())
```

After all, the signal is announced:

```
personChanged = pyqtSignal()
```

That is, it should be:

```
self.personChanged.emit(ix, ix, self.roleNames())
```